# Disabled Sound Through HDMI When i Had Windows

Tags: hdmi, amd-graphics

When I had windows installed i had disabled in the bios sound coming through HDMI so I could use my speakers. I just installed linux yesterday and there's no sound coming through my HDMI cord and under the sound settings there isn't an HDMI setting, is this because I don't have the drivers installed for my ATI Radeon 4850 video card?

Comment: Did you re-enable them in bios?

Comment: not before i installed Linux i completely forgot i had disabled them the computer i isntalled ubuntu is one that i no longer use r

Answer (score 2):

Simply re-enable the HDMI sound in your BIOS, then boot into Ubuntu again. The drivers for your card are already installed, and if better (proprietary) drivers are available, you will be offered to install those.

Once you enable it in the BIOS, you will again have the option to use the HDMI audio. It shows up under sound settings as S/PDIF. Simply select this (see below screen-shot) to use it.

[image: sound settings]